# How to parsing this JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have dictionary of this object: I NSLog like this:

NSLog(@"Result : %@",dictResponse);

I would ask how to parse/store all this data in NSMutableArray

```
Result : (
        {
        IsLoggedIn = 1;
        LoginError = None;
    },
        (
                {
            "delete_Id" = 1;
            "Id_book" = 118;
            "is_read" = 0;
            name = "xxxxxxx";
            "picture" = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/Images/Img_00001181_small.gif";
            "Text_Author" = "Jostein";
        },
                {
            "delete_Id" = 48;
            "Id_book" = 111;
            "Je_read" = 1;
            name = "xxxxx";
            "picture" = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/Images/Img_00001111_small.gif";
            "Text_Author" = "Suzana";
        }
    )
)
```

If I NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[dictResponse valueForKey:@"Id_book"]);
```

I get:

```
(
    "<null>",
        (
        118,
        111
    )
)
```

Comment: You have already parsed the json, your question should be I guess, how to use.. Can you put some code of your parsing?

Answer (score 1):

try

your `objectAtindex : 0` is

```
<null>
```

your `objectAtindex : 1` is

> NSLog(@"%@",[[dictResponse valueForKey:@"Id_book"]objectAtIndex:1]);

Comment: actually we don't  know how do you sterilize the JSON , here I submit my answer is randomly , but it is wrong can you submit your code it is easy to optimize the answer